# User Guided Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to use the Jupyter notebook as a web interface for one Data Science Project, so I think of the following:

1- how to control the notebook, so important processing cells will be hidden and output cells will be shown?

2- how to let the user load the file of CSV or so using the upload functionality of the browser?

3- how to use Jupyter cell as an input place, i.e to make one cell as input for the user then address this cell or call it in another cell.

if this is not applicable with Jupyter, I'd appreciate any advice or reference to another library to let me build this using web.

Comment: Checkout nbgrader : https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: thank you @soumith but this is not for assignments, it is for production.